# Sub-second intervals in AP scheduler

Tags: python, apscheduler

I am running a process in APScheduler that needs to run at a half-second interval, but the 'interval' trigger seems to only accept values down to 1 second (just basing that on the documentation, the second parameter takes an int). Is there a way to get sub-second scheduling on APScheduler, or is there another scheduling library that will allow me to schedule at sub-second intervals and then change that interval midway through.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating the process as a separate thread with an event.

```
def measure_value(self, meas_list, start_time, interval_time, stop_event):
    random.seed()
    while(not stop_event.is_set()):
        stop_event.wait(interval_time)
        measurements = [random.random(), random.random()]
        meas_time = time.time()
        '''
        meas_string = self.inst_ref.query('MEAS:CURR?;VOLT?') #grab the output current and voltage
        measurements = meas_string.split(';')
        '''
        meas_time = meas_time - start_time
        measurements.append(meas_time)
        meastuple = tuple(float(m) for m in measurements)
        meas_list.append(meastuple)
        print(meastuple)
        self.fp.update(meastuple)
```

There is another thread that is eventually called that sets the stop event so that this loop stops executing and the thread closes.